# Select option to unassign value

Tags: forms, drop-down-list

I have a form where I can assign a bundle to an user. In the select are all selectable bundles listed. But I need the possibility to unassign any bundle from an user.

Where to place the "unassignment" action?

My idea is to add one option as first option "No bundle", when selected the user won't get assigned any bundle. Is this intuitive?

Comment: If the "No Bundle" is the default option, then it will be intuitive, as that's set initially and you have to explicity select another one, so it is obvious that you can switch back. Or have a "Bundle" checkbox that enables/disables the dropdown. Depends on user expectations, etc.

Comment: If the user had no bundle assigned before, the inital value is "No Bundle" otherwise the currently assigned bundle is displayed.

Comment: Agreed with Steve; include "no bundle" as one of the options, especially if it's the initial default state. Unless you have a specific reason to think this would confuse users or lead them in a direction you don't want, it sounds intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

The current usage is to add an [x] button to the right of the bundle or whatever. Users know that clicking it, it will vanish.

Comment: It sounds like that would work if the user selected a bundle from the select widget, and then the name of the bundle appeared somewhere else. But if it's only shown in the widget, then having an X button would be redundant.